# Trying to remove email form PHP redirect function and turn it into a pop-up message

Tags: php, javascript, forms, email, redirect

I'm using the code below to send an email to my address alerting me of a new user sign up:

```
<?php
$errors  = '';
$myemail = 'name@mydomain.com';
if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name          = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message       = $_POST['message'];

if (!preg_match(
      "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
      $email_address
   )) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $to            = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Invitation Request: $email_address";
    $email_body    = "has received a new invitation request. " .
                     "\n Email: $email_address";

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
}
?>
```

Currently it redirects users to a new page but instead I want it to allow for a javascript pop-up success/fail message much like those used in modern websites.

Here is the message code (CSS and Javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
/* Status Message */
.message { 
    display: none; 
    margin: 0 0 13px 0; 
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 52px; 
    background: url('icon_check.gif') left no-repeat #EFA; 
    background-position: 13px 5px; 
    border: solid 1px #BD8; '
    width: 300px; 
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Button1").click(function(event){
     $(".message").show();
     $(".message").fadeOut(2500);
   });
 });
</script>
```

and here's the html for the success message:

```
<div class="message">Your Invitation Request Has Been Received!</div>
```

Is it possible to do this? I've looked in several places for the answer over the past two days and I can't seem to change the right thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, the best way to do this would be to redirect back to the signup page with a query string that tells the page to open the window from there.

```
header("Location: /signup.php?success=true");
```

and in the JS

```
<script>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 'true'){
     echo "window.open( '/success.html', 'success', '[options],[..],[..]' );";
}
?>

</script>
```

Also, I recommend using [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate emails.

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Can I put that PHP code anywhere within the php file? Also, the sign up form is on the index page, would I change "signup.php" to "index.php"? I'm completely new at this stuff so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Put the `header()` code where you have `//redirect to the 'thank you' page`. If there is any code after that, add in `exit();` to stop the script's execution (but only do this after you have added the new user to your database). You need to change signup.php to index.php. However, I would add your full domain name to it (e.g. http(s)://example.com/?success=true).

Comment: Ah perfect you fixed the redirect problem...now to figure out how to post a failure message if what's entered is not a proper email address. The code does redirect when whatever is entered into the input box is not a correct email address.

Comment: First, set `$errors  = '';` to `$errors  = false;`. Then do `if($errors) {header("Location: http(s)://example.com/?success=false&description=$errors"); exit();}`. and simply open an error page, or better yet just open an `alert()` with the error

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this so to combine your PHP mail function with your HTML page. You could use AJAX to load the send mail PHP page into a DIV, which will overwrite the content of that DIV with whatever the resulting output of the PHP function is. This would allow you to have a fallback for users without JS since submitting the form to the PHP page would still work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wish I knew how to do any of that. I'm pretty new to this stuff.